# Wordpress media file link with fancybox

Tags: media

I am trying to use fancybox with my wordpress theme I am working on for a client. I want the images to load into a fancbox overlay when choosing "link to media file" after inserting an image in wordpress. I seem to have it linked up correctly but the image always says "cannot load url at this time" when the overlay pops up and I am a bit stuck on what's going on. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Here is my code I am using to adjust the output of an image with a link to the media file.

```
function add_rel_lightbox($content)
{

    /* Find internal links */

    //Check the page for link images direct to image (no trailing attributes)
    $string = '/<a href="(.*?).(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|ico)"><img(.*?)class="(.*?)wp-image-(.*?)" \/><\/a>/i';
    preg_match_all( $string, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    //Check which attachment is referenced
    foreach ($matches as $val)
    {
        $slimbox_caption = '';

        $post = get_post($val[5]);
        $slimbox_caption = esc_attr( $post->post_content );

        //Replace the instance with the lightbox and title(caption) references. Won't fail if caption is empty.
        $string = '<a href="' . $val[1] . '.' . $val[2] . '"><img' . $val[3] . 'class="' . $val[4] . 'wp-image-' . $val[5] . '" /></a>';
        $replace = '<a href="' . $val[1] . '.' . $val[2] . '" rel="group" title="' . $slimbox_caption . '"><img' . $val[3] . 'class="fancybox ' . $val[4] . 'wp-image-' . $val[5] . '" /></a>';
        $content = str_replace( $string, $replace, $content);
    }

    return $content;
}

/* Filter Hook */

add_filter('the_content', 'add_rel_lightbox', 2);
```

Thanks again for taking the time to help out.

Ponte